# npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script

Tags: angular-material, angular6

[image]

I'm getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@3.1.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yaeesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-07T10_36_05_651Z-debug.log
```

Comment: nope..npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script. im getting this error when i run npm install

Comment: no..still the same error..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by removing my latest nodejs, 12.3.1, and installing the last version of 11

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/

Comment: The was the problem (resolved) https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/409

Comment: Spent a lot of time trying to fix this. This answer really helped. Thanks!!